# JavaScript getter for all properties

Tags: javascript, firefox, getter

Long story short: I'm in a situation where I'd like a PHP-style getter, but in JavaScript.

My JavaScript is running in Firefox only, so Mozilla specific JS is OK by me.

The only way I can find to make a JS getter requires specifying its name, but I'd like to define a getter for *all* possible names.  I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'd very much like to know.

Comment: i imagine he's referring to the magic functions __get and __set

Answer (score 130, accepted):

`Proxy` can do it! I'm so happy this exists!! An answer is given here: [Is there a javascript equivalent of python's __getattr__ method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529496/is-there-a-javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-getattr-method) . To rephrase in my own words:

```js
var x = new Proxy({}, {
  get(target, name) {
    return "Its hilarious you think I have " + name
  }
})

console.log(x.hair) // logs: "Its hilarious you think I have hair"
```

Proxy for the win! Check out the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Works in chrome, firefox, and node.js. Downsides: doesn't work in IE - freakin IE. Soon.

Comment: It works in Edge too. See [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=proxy) for specific browser versions.

Comment: but what if I want to mimic a function call, like myProxy.foo('bar'). I've seen there is apply for functions but is not allowed to use custom names, is always executed on the proxy: myProxy('bar'), we could mimic it with myProxy('foo', 'bar') but then we are missing the magic thing

Comment: @Enrique If you return a function from the getter, you should absolutely be able to call `myProxy.foo('bar')`.

Comment: I recognize the answer is correct for the question, but for readers like me who want a default return value, beware that the proxy takes precedence.

Comment: @BarryMcNamara Could you clarify what you mean that the proxy takes precedence?

Comment: The handler traps calls to the target object. If your target has properties which you want to continue to be gettable, you need to explicitly return them from the handler's get method.

Answer (score 77):

You can combine proxy and class to have a **nice looking code like php**:

```
class Magic {
    constructor () {
        return new Proxy(this, this);
    }
    get (target, prop) {
        return this[prop] || 'MAGIC';
    }
}
```

this binds to the handler, so you can use this instead of target.

**Note: unlike PHP, proxy handles all prop access.**

```
let magic = new Magic();
magic.foo = 'NOT MAGIC';
console.log(magic.foo); // NOT MAGIC
console.log(magic.bar); // MAGIC
```

You can check which browsers support proxy http://caniuse.com/#feat=proxy.

Comment: This is the best answer I've found.

Comment: ^ this is genius

Comment: is not needed to implement "set" inside the proxy for the assignment?

Comment: @Enrique No, it works like regular objects, but you can define it.

Comment: simply magical!

Answer (score 46):

The closest you can find is [__noSuchMethod__](https://web.archive.org/web/20210224190946/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/Object.noSuchMethod) ([__noSuchMethod__ is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#object_methods)), which is JavaScript's equivalent of PHP's __call().

Unfortunately, there's no equivalent of __get/__set, which is a shame, because with them we could have implemented __noSuchMethod__, but I don't yet see a way to implement properties (as in C#) using __noSuchMethod__.

```
var foo = {
    __noSuchMethod__ : function(id, args) {
        alert(id);
        alert(args);
    }
};

foo.bar(1, 2);
```

Comment: I was actually trying to create a "message eating nil" equivalent, and this does it *exactly*!  Thanks!

Comment: I had no idea about the "message eating nil" concept. Thanks

Comment: What about nowjs?  They have to be using some sort of __set() and __get() equivalent to make their RPC-style framework actually work.  I can't tell how it works from the source code.

Comment: is there something similar for Chrome/Awesomium? I also found another concept using [Harmony Proxies](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3757676/648980), which unfortunately only works in FF right now.

Comment: @Towa `Proxy` is the future indeed. It's available on Chrome if you enable experimental JavaScript features under "about:flags". There's no other equivalent for `__noSuchMethod__`.

Comment: __noSuchMethod__ is non standard and no version of Internet Explorer support it, so it may not work on many of your users' browser.

Comment: What about ECMAScript analog of this?

Comment: **IMPORTANT:** The link says now: *This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.*

Comment: While __noSuchMethod__ has been dropped, the ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) specification has the Proxy object, with which you can achieve the below (and more).

Comment: What is the current status of __noSuchMethod__ ? I cannot find in caniuse, and I think is much better than Proxy, because with proxy we cannot fake a function call

Answer (score 5):

[Javascript 1.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference) does have [getter/setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/get_Operator) [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).  It's explained very well by John Resig [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/)

It's not generic enough for web use, but certainly Firefox has them (also Rhino, if you ever want to use it on the server side).

Comment: Not quite __get() and __set().  PHP's version let you monitor ALL properties, even ones that haven't been created yet.

Answer (score 5):

If you really need an implementation that works, you could "cheat" your way arround by testing the second parameter against `undefined`, this also means you could use get to actually set parameter.

```
var foo = {
    args: {},

    __noSuchMethod__ : function(id, args) {
        if(args === undefined) {
            return this.args[id] === undefined ? this[id] : this.args[id]
        }

        if(this[id] === undefined) {
            this.args[id] = args;
        } else {
            this[id] = args;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something like PHP's [`__get()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) function, I don't think Javascript provides any such construct.

The best I can think of doing is looping through the object's non-function members and then creating a corresponding "getXYZ()" function for each.

In dodgy pseudo-ish code:

```
for (o in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(o)) {
        this['get_' + o] = function() {
            // return this.o -- but you'll need to create a closure to
            // keep the correct reference to "o"
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a nickfs' answer to construct my own solution. My solution will automatically create get_{propname} and set_{propname} functions for all properties. It does check if the function already exists before adding them. This allows you to override the default get or set method with our own implementation without the risk of it getting overwritten.

```
for (o in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(o)) {
            var creategetter = (typeof this['get_' + o] !== 'function');
            var createsetter = (typeof this['set_' + o] !== 'function');
            (function () {
                var propname = o;
                if (creategetter) {
                    self['get_' + propname] = function () {
                        return self[propname];
                    };
                }
                if (createsetter) {
                    self['set_' + propname] = function (val) {
                        self[propname] = val;
                    };
                }
            })();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer to the original question, however [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529496/is-there-a-javascript-equivalent-of-pythons-getattr-method) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441005/pythons-getattr-in-javascript) questions are closed and redirect here, so here I am. I hope I can help some other JS newbie that lands here as I did.

Coming from Python, what I was looking for was an equivalent of `obj.__getattr__(key)`and `obj.__hasattr__(key)` methods. What I ended up using is:
`obj[key]` for `getattr` and `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` for `hasattr` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get a similar result simply by wrapping the object in a getter function:

```js
const getProp = (key) => {
  const dictionary = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    age: 42,
    DEFAULT: 'there is no prop like this'
  }
  return (typeof dictionary[key] === 'undefined' ? dictionary.DEFAULT : dictionary[key]);
}

console.log(getProp('age')) // 42

console.log(getProp('Hello World')) // 'there is no prop like this'
```