# Is there an equivalent of the __noSuchMethod__ feature for properties, or a way to implement it in JS?

Tags: javascript

There is a **noSuchMethod** feature in some javascript implementations (Rhino, SpiderMonkey)

```
proxy = {
    __noSuchMethod__: function(methodName, args){
        return "The " + methodName + " method isn't implemented yet. HINT: I accept cash and beer bribes" ;
    },

    realMethod: function(){
     return "implemented" ;   
    }
}

js> proxy.realMethod()
implemented
js> proxy.newIPod()
The newIPod method isn't implemented yet. HINT: I accept cash and beer bribes
js>
```

I was wondering, is there was a way to do something similar for properties? I'd like to write proxy classes that can dispatch on properties as well as methods.

Comment: The question was prompted more by curiosity than by need, I was trying to use Rhino as a script engine for a Java application and that involved creating js wrappers for host objects and their methods - and properties. In the end I switched to Clojure because it made talking to Java a lot easier, though incidentally creating dynamic proxies is actually harder in Clojure than in Javascript.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11144589/1348195 I also posted an answer there using the new proxy API.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**UPDATE:** ECMAScript 6 Proxies are [widely supported now](https://caniuse.com/#search=proxy). Basically, if you don't need to support IE11, you can use them.

Proxy objects allow you to define custom behavior for fundamental operations, like property lookup, assignment, enumeration, function invocation, etc.

## Emulating __noSuchMethod__ with ES6 Proxies

By implementing traps on property access, you can emulate the behavior of the non-standard `__noSuchMethod__` trap:

```js
function enableNoSuchMethod(obj) {
  return new Proxy(obj, {
    get(target, p) {
      if (p in target) {
        return target[p];
      } else if (typeof target.__noSuchMethod__ == "function") {
        return function(...args) {
          return target.__noSuchMethod__.call(target, p, args);
        };
      }
    }
  });
}

// Example usage:

function Dummy() {
  this.ownProp1 = "value1";
  return enableNoSuchMethod(this);
}

Dummy.prototype.test = function() {
  console.log("Test called");
};

Dummy.prototype.__noSuchMethod__ = function(name, args) {
  console.log(`No such method ${name} called with ${args}`);
  return;
};

var instance = new Dummy();
console.log(instance.ownProp1);
instance.test();
instance.someName(1, 2);
instance.xyz(3, 4);
instance.doesNotExist("a", "b");
```

### Original 2010 answer

There is only one existing thing at the moment that can actually do what you want, but unfortunately is not widely implemented:

- [ECMAScript Harmony Proxies](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proxies).

There are only *two working* implementations available at this time, in the latest Firefox 4 betas (it has been around since FF3.7 pre-releases) and in [node-proxy](https://npmjs.org/package/node-proxy) for server-side JavaScript -[Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=633) and [Safari](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35731) are currently working on it-.

It is one of the [early proposals](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proposals&s=harmony) for the [next version of ECMAScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#ECMAScript_Harmony), it's an API that allows you to implement *virtualized* objects (proxies), where you can assign a variety of *traps* -callbacks- that are executed in different situations, you gain full control on what at this time -in ECMAScript 3/5- only host objects could do.

To build a proxy object, you have to use the `Proxy.create` method, since you are interested in the `set` and `get` traps, I leave you a really simple example:

```
var p = Proxy.create({
  get: function(proxy, name) {        // intercepts property access
    return 'Hello, '+ name;
  },
  set: function(proxy, name, value) { // intercepts property assignments
    alert(name +'='+ value);
    return true;
  }
});

alert(p.world); // alerts 'Hello, world'
p.foo = 'bar';  // alerts foo=bar
```

Try it out [here](http://jsbin.com/ucupe4/edit).

**EDIT:** The proxy API evolved, the `Proxy.create` method was removed in favor of using the `Proxy` constructor, see the above code updated to ES6:

```js
const obj = {};
const p = new Proxy(obj, {
  get(target, prop) {        // intercepts property access
    return 'Hello, '+ prop;
  },
  set(target, prop, value, receiver) { // intercepts property assignments
    console.log(prop +'='+ value);
    Reflect.set(target, prop, value, receiver)
    return true;
  }
});

console.log(p.world);
p.foo = 'bar';
```

The Proxy API is so new that isn't even documented on the Mozilla Developer Center, but as I said, a working implementation has been included since the Firefox 3.7 pre-releases.

The `Proxy` object is available in the global scope and the `create` method can take two arguments, a `handler` object, which is simply an object that contains properties named as the traps you want to implement, and an optional `proto` argument, that makes you able to specify an object that your proxy inherits from.

The traps available are:

```
// TrapName(args)                          Triggered by
// Fundamental traps
getOwnPropertyDescriptor(name):           // Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(proxy, name)
getPropertyDescriptor(name):              // Object.getPropertyDescriptor(proxy, name) [currently inexistent in ES5]
defineProperty(name, propertyDescriptor): // Object.defineProperty(proxy,name,pd)
getOwnPropertyNames():                    // Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proxy) 
getPropertyNames():                       // Object.getPropertyNames(proxy) 
delete(name):                             // delete proxy.name
enumerate():                              // for (name in proxy)
fix():                                    // Object.{freeze|seal|preventExtensions}(proxy)

// Derived traps
has(name):                                // name in proxy
hasOwn(name):                             // ({}).hasOwnProperty.call(proxy, name)
get(receiver, name):                      // receiver.name
set(receiver, name, val):                 // receiver.name = val
keys():                                   // Object.keys(proxy)
```

The only resource I've seen, besides the proposal by itself, is the following tutorial:

- [Harmony Proxies: Tutorial](http://prog.vub.ac.be/%7Etvcutsem/proxies/index.html)

**Edit:** More information is coming out, Brendan Eich recently gave a talk at the [JSConf.eu](http://JSConf.eu) Conference, you can find his slides here:

- [Proxies are Awesome!](http://jsconf.eu/2010/speaker/be_proxy_objects.html)

Comment: The Brendan Eich video seems to be no longer available at the JSConf.eu website. [Luckily it is on YouTube now](http://youtu.be/sClk6aB_CPk).

Comment: Chrome has Proxy too.

Comment: While extensive, this answer completely misses the fact that the question was focusing on calling _methods_ not accessing properties! Not the same thing.

Comment: @ValeriuPaloş: I added an example of how you can emulate the non-standard  `__noSuchMethod__` trap by using ES6 Proxies.

Comment: For one of my situations I was getting errors which I think was due to the fact that the `enableNoSuchMethod else if return` returns a function rather than a result/value, so by making that function into a IIFE, this solved the issue. Can anyone comment on if makes sense? Not 100% confident on Proxies yet. I think its related to whether the missing thing is called as an attribute or function, but thats a guess at this point. However, for other ones it needed to be as the original (not IIFE) in order for the args to come through correctly. Was this maybe due to the spread operator?

Answer (score 7):

Here's how to get behaviour similar to __noSuchMethod__

First of all, here's a simple object with one method:

```
var myObject = {
    existingMethod: function (param) {
        console.log('existing method was called', param);
    }
}
```

Now create a Proxy which will catch access to properties/method and add your existing object as a first parameter.

```
var myObjectProxy = new Proxy(myObject, {
   get: function (func, name) {
       // if property or method exists, return it
       if( name in myObject ) {
           return myObject[name];
       }
       // if it doesn't exists handle non-existing name however you choose
       return function (args) {
           console.log(name, args);
       }
    }
});
```

Now try it:

```
myObjectProxy.existingMethod('was called here');
myObjectProxy.nonExistingMethod('with a parameter');
```

Works in Chrome/Firefox/Opera. Doesn't work in IE(but already works in Edge). Also tested on mobile Chrome.

Creation of proxy can be automated and invisible i.e. if you use Factory pattern to build your objects. I did that to create workers which internal functions can be called directly from the main thread. Using workers can be now so simple thanks to this cool new feature called Proxy. The simplest worker implementation ever:

```
var testWorker = createWorker('pathTo/testWorker.js');
testWorker.aFunctionInsideWorker(params, function (result) {
    console.log('results from worker: ', result);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe this type of metaprogramming is possible (yet) in javascript.  Instead, try using the `__noSuchMethod__` functionality to achieve the effect with property getters.  Not cross-browser as it's a [Mozilla extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/NoSuchMethod).

```
var proxy = {
    __noSuchMethod__: function(methodName, args) {
       if(methodName.substr(0,3)=="get") {
          var property = methodName.substr(3).toLowerCase();                             
          if (property in this) {
              return this[property];
          }
       }
    }, color: "red"
 };
 alert(proxy.getColor());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) class.

```
var myObj = {
    someAttr: 'foo'
};

var p = new Proxy(myObj, {
    get: function (target, propName) {
        // target is the first argument passed into new Proxy,
        // in this case target === myObj
        return 'myObj with someAttr:"' + target.someAttr 
               + '" had "' + propName 
               + '" called on it.';
    }
});
console.log(p.nonExsistantProperty);
// outputs: 
// myObj with someAttr:"foo" had "nonExsistantProperty" called on it
```

Answer (score 0):

There is `__defineGetter__`, `__defineSetter__`, `__lookupGetter__` and `__lookupSetter__` in addition to `__noSuchMethod__` in SpiderMonkey.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question I was looking into this today.  I wanted to be able to seamlessly integrate code from another context, maybe a different web page or server.

Its the sort of thing that breaks in the long run, but I think its an interesting concept none the less. These things can be useful for mashing code together quickly, ( which then exists for years, buried somewhere ).

```js
var mod = modproxy();

mod.callme.first.now('hello', 'world');

mod.hello.world.plot = 555;

var v = mod.peter.piper.lucky.john.valueOf;
console.log(v);

mod.hello.world = function(v) {
  alert(v);
  return 777;
};

var v = mod.hello.world('funky...');
console.log(v);

var v = mod.hello.world.plot.valueOf;
console.log(v);

mod.www.a(99);
mod.www.b(98);

function modproxy(__notfound__) {

  var mem = {};          
  return newproxy();

  function getter(target, name, receiver, lname) {

    if(name === 'valueOf') {
      lname=lname.slice(1);

      if(lname in mem) {
        var v = mem[lname];
        console.log(`rd : ${lname} - ${v}`);
        return v;
      }

      console.log(`rd (not found) : ${lname}`);
      return;
    }

    lname += '.'+name;
    return newproxy(() => {}, lname);

  } // getter

  function setter(obj, prop, newval, lname) {

    lname += '.' + prop;
    lname = lname.slice(1);
    console.log(`wt : ${lname} - ${newval}`);
    mem[lname] = newval;

  } // setter

  function applyer(target, thisArg, args, lname) {

    lname = lname.slice(1);

    if(lname in mem) {
      var v = mem[lname];

      if(typeof v === 'function') {
        console.log(`fn : ${lname} - [${args}]`);
        return v.apply(thisArg,args);
      }

      return v;

    }

    console.log(`fn (not found): ${lname} - [${args}]`);

  } // applyer

  function newproxy(target, lname) {

    target = target || {};
    lname = lname || '';

    return new Proxy(target, {
      get: (target, name, receiver) => {
        return getter(target, name, receiver, lname);
      },
      set: (target, name, newval) => {
        return setter(target, name, newval, lname);
      },
      apply: (target, thisArg, args) => {
        return applyer(target, thisArg, args, lname);
      }
    });

  } //proxy

} //modproxy
```

I implemented a `valueOf` step to read values, because it seems the property is 'get-ted' first.

I dont think its possible to tell at the time the property is 'get-ted' if its going to be invoked or read ( or required for further chaining ).

Its ok for single level properties. The property is either there or its not and either the required type or its not.

I'll work on it further, looking at promises for async/await routines, proxying existing objects and finer control of how properties are accessed when I am more familiar with how the code behaves and is best implemented.

I created a repository on GitHub: [modproxy.js/README.md](https://github.com/javascript-2020/modproxy.js/blob/main/README.md)

CodePen: [modproxy.js](https://codepen.io/matt-2016/pen/ZEpaZyb)

My original question:

[does javascript have an equivalent to the php magic class __call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65455451/does-javascript-have-an-equivalent-to-the-php-magic-class-call/65458583#65458583)