# doesNotUnderstand for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, smalltalk

Is there a way to simulate Smalltalk's doesNotUnderstand or Ruby's method_missing in Javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no catch-all method defined in the JavaScript standard, but Mozilla implements the non-standard [`__noSuchMethod__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod) for [SpiderMonkey](http://www.mozilla.org/js/spidermonkey/) and [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) (including Firefox obviously).

You may also be interested in checking out [@CMS' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266789/is-there-an-equivalent-of-the-nosuchmethod-feature-for-properties-or-a-way-t/3757676#3757676) given to the following Stack Overflow question:

- [Is there an equivalent of the **noSuchMethod** feature for properties, or a way to implement it in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266789/is-there-an-equivalent-of-the-nosuchmethod-feature-for-properties-or-a-way-t)