# JavaScript: Use Object As Array

Tags: javascript

Are there any pitfalls to code like this?

```
var Foo = function() {
    this.bar = function() { return 'bar'; };
};

var f = new Foo();
f[0] = 'hi';
f[1] = 'there';
```

Note that I'm creating a new function object with some misc properties, and then I'm treating the object like an array. Also how are the array values being stored in the object? Are 0 and 1 treated like property names?

Comment: As long as you don't have a length-property no one will confuse your object with an array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, yes, `0`, and `1` will be just two property names.

When you assign a property with the bracket notation, the expression between the brackets will be converted to String, and that string will be used as the property name.

In fact, even the *indexes* for *real arrays* are just that, properties:

```
var realArray = ['a'];
realArray.hasOwnProperty('0'); // true
```

The difference is that *real array* objects on every property assignment that correspond to a valid *index*<sup>[1]</sup>, track internally the value of their `length` property.

That's one of the reasons why "subclassing" array objects is difficult, [even with the new  ECMAScript 5 extensions](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/), or at the moment also with the proposed [ECMAScript-Harmony Proxies](http://gist.github.com/533954) <sub>[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266789/is-there-an-equivalent-of-the-nosuchmethod-feature-for-properties-or-a-way-t/3757676#3757676) [3](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proxies)</sub>, can't be completely done, in a stanard way.

That can be a problem, depending on how you plan to *iterate* the numeric properties.

If you enumerate the properties with the `for-in` statement, other members will appear, not just the numeric properties.

<sub>[1] A valid array index is any unsigned 32-bit integer in the range of 0 to (2^32)-1.</sub>

Comment: I'm a little surprised. That means there are no real arrays in Javascript. Only an object with a few array-type functions bolted on.

Comment: @mellowsoon: That's absolutely right. All JavaScript objects, including arrays, are just a collection of properties.

Comment: @mellowsoon, exactly, arrays are simply objects that have an special [`\[\[DefineOwnProperty\]\]`](http://ecma262-5.com/els5_html.htm#Section_15.4.5.1) internal method, (amongst other few peculiar characteristics). This internal method is used when you make a property assignment, and it takes care to track and compute the value of the `length` property.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have problems if you try to loop through that with a `for in` loop; the loop will also get `bar`. There are ways around this, so you just have to be careful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extend Array behavious please use : `Array.prototype.yourfunc = function()....`