# Define a Universal/Fallback getter property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, getter

JavaScript has getters with `Object.defineProperty`. So I can define a getter on the property `random` of `window` by

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'random', {
    get: function () {
        return Math.random();
    }
});

random // Evaluates to a random number
```

Is it possible to define a "universal getter" for a given object, regardless of the object property? I am looking to do something like

```
Object.universalGetter(window, function (propertyName) {
     console.log('Accessing property', propertyName, 'of window.');
});

window.Function // Prints "Accessing property Function of window."
```

Can I do "universal getters" in JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to implement dynamic getters/setters in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891937/is-it-possible-to-implement-dynamic-getters-setters-in-javascript)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266789/is-there-an-equivalent-of-the-nosuchmethod-feature-for-properties-or-a-way

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

It is not possible to do in ECMAScript 5th edition as *there is no provision for this operation.* While such is not explicit stated, it can be seen that [[GetProperty]](http://es5.github.com/#x8.12.2) does not make any provisions for non-existing properties.

The getters/setters in ECMAScript *require* existing properties and there is no equivalent of Ruby's `method_missing` or Python's `__getattribute__`.

Answer (score 18):

Unfortunately: No, there isn't.

There is somehthing called [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) Objects Introduced in Gecko 18 based Browsers

Which would allow you to do things like this

```
(function (original, Window) {
  var handler = {
    get: function (target, propertyName) {
      console.log('Accessing property', propertyName, 'of window.');
      return target[propertyName];
    }
  };

  Window = new Proxy(original, handler);


  console.log(Window.setTimeout); 
  // "Accessing property"
  //  "setTimeout"
  //  "of window."
  
  // function setTimeout() {
  //  [native code]
  // }
})(window);
```

But this is **not** Standard and still very unstable

*Btw I originally thought you could directly use `window` as local variable in the IIFE but it seems you can't it just logs undefined (wondering why) so I capitalized the "W"*

Heres an example on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ucezej/1/edit)

*Note: You should visit it in Firefox*

Comment: [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) is now standard and being implemented as part of ES2015