# javascript: implement something like python's __getattribute__?

Tags: javascript, python, dynamic, duck-typing

Is there a way to implement in javascript the functionality of python's __getattribute__() (or __getattr__())? That is, a method which is called whenever an object is called with method name or property name which cannot be resolved?

For example, a mechanism to implement any of the following:

```
# Python's method syntax 
o.Name(args) # o.__getattr__('Name') is called and returns 
             # a function which is called with args
# Alternative method syntax
o.Name(args) # o.__getattr__('Name', args) is called and returns a value

# Properties syntax
o.Name = v  # o.__getattr__('Name', v) is called
v = o.Name  # o.__getattr__('Name') is called and returns a value
```

I'm most interested in the method syntax, but the property syntax would be a nice bonus. Thanks!

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266789/is-there-an-equivalent-of-the-nosuchmethod-feature-for-properties-or-a-way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @thg435 the issue was discussed in a narrower scope at [Is there an equivalent of the __noSuchMethod__ feature for properties, or a way to implement it in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266789/is-there-an-equivalent-of-the-nosuchmethod-feature-for-properties-or-a-way) but the answer from there applies here.

An appropriate API for doing this in javascript is in the making, called [ECMAScript Harmony Proxies](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proxies) which may have been replaced recently with [Direct Proxy](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:direct_proxies). This API is not yet supported cross-platform, but it may work for some platform, such as recent firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = { 
  attr1 : 0,
  attr2 : 2
}

// Object {attr1: 0, attr2: 2}

function get(obj, attr) {
  return obj[attr];
}

get(a, 'attr2');

// 2
```

Another approach is to have the method inside the object:

```
a = { 
  attr1 : 0,
  attr2 : 2,
  myfunc: function(args) {
    alert(args);
  },
  get   : function(attr) {
    return this[attr];
  }
}

// Object {attr1: 0, attr2: 2, get: function}

a.get('attr2');

// 2
```

if what you get is function you can call it straight away `a.get('myfunc')('myarg')` alerts `myarg`

Comment: I was hoping to have a more 'automatic' approach which will work for 'a.attr3'...

Comment: @UriCohen well of course you can get an attribute value via `a.attr2`, and if it's a function you can call it `a.myfunc()`