# Is there such a thing as a catch-all key for a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, function, key, default, catch-all

Considering the following javascript example:

```
var myobj = {   func1: function() { alert(name in this) },
                func2: function() { alert(name in this) },
                func3: function() { alert(name in this) }
}

myobj.func2(); // returns true
myobj.func4(); // undefined function
```

Is it possible to create a 'catch-all' key for `myobj` that will get called if there is no key/function defined (as in `func4()`) while retaining the `myobj.functionCall()` format?

Comment: Really? Care to point to one? If you can find one, I'll delete the question.

Comment: @Pointy - are you saying that you can't imagine how it could be implemented in the language? If so, how about a wildcard key like * ?

Comment: I'm saying that I'm too dumb to imagine how it'd be implemented :-) Also, the semantics seem like they'd be complicated; would you just get one wildcard entry?  What if you set its value to the number 37 instead of a function?

Comment: @patrick: there was a question very much like yours last week... can't find it though...

Comment: Found it, placed it as answer =)

Comment: @jidupont - I've found similar questions that offer workarounds that change the format of the function call. That's no problem. This question is more about whether or not a feature exists in the language to either provide a catch-all or wildcard key, or whether there's some tricky way to accomplish the same effect.

Comment: @Pointy - Keys are unique, therefore only one wildcard would be allowed (in my imaginary world). If it didn't contain a function, you would presumably get the same result as you would if you tried to call a function against any other key that doesn't contain one.

Comment: Yes I guess that'd work. Something seems a little kludgey about it, but whatever; it's Javascript, after all :-)

Comment: @Pointy - **but whatever; it's Javascript, after all :-) ** How true! :o)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're looking for `__noSuchMethod__`:
[JavaScript getter for all properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994143/javascript-getter-for-all-properties)

Comment: Hmmm... I tried it `__noSuchMethod__: function() { alert('caught it') },` but it isn't getting called.

Comment: Interesting... it is getting called when I use Firefox, but not Safari.

Comment: Probably because it must be Gecko-restricted... Too bad, Mozilla addressed this method as "Non-standard".

Comment: Tried it with the args. No change. Still works in FF, but not Safari.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod - at top it says it's "Non-standard". You may have to go with ugly syntax instead.

Comment: So the answer is that it is not a standard feature of javascript. Sound right?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it's not part of the JavaScript standard.

Answer (score 39):

You can create a JavaScript object with 'wildcard' or 'catch-all' keys using a Proxy and a getter function. Unlike the solutions provided, a Proxy should work in just about any environment, including Node.js

```
var foo = new Object()

var specialFoo = new Proxy(foo, {
    get(target,name) {
        // do something here
        return name
    }
})

console.log(specialFoo.blabla) // this will output "blabla"
```

If you want the properties to be callable, simply return a function:

```
var specialFoo = new Proxy(foo, {
    get(target,name) {
        return function() {
            console.log('derp')
            return name
        }
    }
})


specialFoo.callMe() // this will print derp
```

Details: [documentation on mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: "about any environment", but not IE :(

Comment: @Christian You can use a polyfill for proxies in IE. Just include <script src="proxy.js"></script> if needed. See more information here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/proxy-polyfill

Comment: At least that polyfill does not support the use case: "This means that the properties you want to proxy must be known at creation time."

Comment: @Christian Hmm. Really? There is no way to implement a catch all proxy working on IE at all, period? Not on any version? Other polyfills maybe? I would like to know this for sure. Can you confirm?

Comment: Well, that cite was from the link you provided. I don't know if it would be possible to create another polyfill... at least I have not found one which can do it.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/krzkaczor/babel-plugin-proxy/blob/master/src/runtime.js

Comment: Maybe that'd be worth a try, but it's documentation states "It is not suitable for production environments because performance impact is huge."