# Delegate Javascript Functions

Tags: javascript

As an siginificantly simplified scenario, say I have 2 Javascript objects defined as below:

```
var ClassA = Class.extend({
    'say': function(message) {
        console.log(message);
    }

    ... // some more methods ...
});

var ClassB = Class.extend({
    init: function(obj) {
        this._target = obj;
    }
});
```

I'd suppose that in Javascript there is some kind of mechanism could enable us to do the following trick:

```
var b = new ClassB( new ClassA() );
b.say("hello");
```

I'd like to find a way to detect if there is a method called upon `ClassB`, and the method is not defined in `ClassB`, then I can automatically forward the method call to be upon `ClassA`, which is a member variable in `ClassB`.

In a realworld scenario, `ClassA` is an object implemented as brwoser plugin and inserted into the webpage using `<object>` tag. It's method is implemented in C++ code so there is no way I can tell its methods from its prototype and insert it to `ClassB`'s prototype beforehand.

I'd like to use the technical to create a native Javascript object, with a narraw-ed version of ClassA's interface. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Sounds like you actually want ClassB to inherit the functions of ClassA. Anyway, `Class.extend({})` is no native JS mechanism, what framework are you using?

Comment: @pixelistik I believe he added an extend method to `Object`.

Comment: @pixelistik in project I am using JS.Class (http://jsclass.jcoglan.com), while in this example I am using John Resig's Simple Inheritance (http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/). Should not have too much difference though.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a quick cross-browser solution to this.

If you only need Firefox, then use [`__noSuchMethod__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod)

See here: [is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-catch-all-key-for-a-javascript-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357618/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-catch-all-key-for-a-javascript-object)
and here: [javascript-getter-for-all-properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994143/javascript-getter-for-all-properties)

Otherwise, I would try something like this:

```
var b = new ClassB( new ClassA() );

// functionToCall is a string containing the function name
function callOnB(functionToCall) {
    if(typeof b[functionToCall] === function) {
        b[functionToCall]();
    } else {
        b._target[functionToCall](); // otherwise, try calling on A
    }
}
```

This is using the [Square Bracket Notation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html) where

```
b.say('hello')
```

is the same as

```
b['say']('hello')
```

Of course, you should probably expand this to take arguments in:

```
function callOnB(functionToCall, listOfArguments) {...}
```

Comment: BTW, some sorts of evil browser objects (like IE xml stuffs) might give type errors if you access b[functionName] like that or might return "object" to the typeof. You might want to just do a `(functionToCall in b)` test instead.

Comment: Also, since we are talking about evil plugin objects, they might not have a call or apply method so you might need to do something like `switch(args.length){ case 1: return f(a) case 2: return f(a,b); ... }` to manually handle multiple arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to jfrej's hint on **noSunchMethod**, I did some more research on it and it turns out what I need is quit fit with Harmony Proxies([here](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aproxies) and [here](http://prog.vub.ac.be/~tvcutsem/proxies/index.html)). And an example can be found at http://jsbin.com/ucupe4/edit#source

Another related post: http://dailyjs.com/2010/03/12/nosuchmethod/