# Imitate PHP's __get(), __set() & __call() magic methods in Node.js

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, v8, magic-methods

I was wondering if there is a way to imitate PHP's magic methods __get() and __set() in Node. From this question: [JavaScript getter for all properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994143/javascript-getter-for-all-properties) I know you can do it in Rhino, but Node's built on V8. Does V8 have some way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No answer?  Check out nowjs.  They seem to have found a way to make __get() and __set() work in JavaScript.  I can't figure out how they do it from the source code.  :(

**EDIT:** Check out [Monitor All JavaScript Object Properties (magic getters and setters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985582/monitor-all-javascript-object-properties-magic-getters-and-setters)

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to take a look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're out of luck, at least [as of March 2010](http://dailyjs.com/2010/03/12/nosuchmethod/). At least you have `__defineGetter__` and `__defineSetter__`, though I realize that's not the same thing. In general I think using `__noSuchMethod__`/`__get`/`method_missing` is not good since it makes the code harder to read. Consider trying to get by without it and see if it makes your code clearer.

Comment: Thanks Brian! I'll just try those methods and see if they will work. I think they would make the code harder to read if they were all over the place, but I think there are significant use cases if these methods are used internally. I like the prospect of being able to setup chains like this: `Message().action('join').groups([...]).message('Hi world!').send()` where some of these methods aren't defined and if they aren't append to an internal object.

Comment: Chaining and method missing stuff are unrelated. As long as `Message` instances define `action`, `groups`, `message`, and `send` to return `this`, it'll work fine. Obviously you can't have dynamic methods, but that's the price you pay I guess. Why I think it'd be hard to read isn't because you're using `__noSuchMethod__`, but because you'd be taking advantage of them everywhere. Let's say the `message` function above is one such dynamic function, and I want to see where it's defined. I can't just search for the function definition, I have to understand that there's a dynamic handler in play.

Comment: Whoops. I think I forgot to respond to this. I totally agree that they're unrelated, *unless* they aren't defined in Message, as you said. I want those to be attributes defined on-the-fly that can be chained together. I think this style of syntax for building up objects is damn sexy :-)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [my following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48813036/7152817) that explains how one might tackle this with the use of [ES6 proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).