# How to implement __get __set object methods in Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

How to implement __get __set PHP in Javascript?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? What have you looked into?

Comment: Can you add some greater detail?

Comment: The question was closed as "not a real question" but I think it's legit but duplicate. Start looking for your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985582/monitor-all-javascript-object-properties-magic-getters-and-setters

Comment: unbanned me, please .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) with apprpriate parameters.

Comment: Perfect!! Note compatibility with older IE browsers <= 8 is limited or non existent.

Comment: This is not the same thing as the PHP __get and __set magic methods, as it required the getter and setter be defined on a named property, the magic methods in PHP are specifically useful for setting getters and setters when the property does not exist.