# Javascript (ECMA-6) class magic method __call like PHP

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is my use case

```
getSomeFields(persons, fields){

    let personsWithSpecificFields = [];

    _.each(persons, (person) => {

        let personSpecificFields = {};

        _.each(fields, (field) => {
            // here im thinking to modify the field to match the method name 
            // ( if something like __call as in php is available)
            // e.g. field is first_name and i want to change it to getFirstName
            personSpecificFields[field] = person[field]();

        });

        personsWithSpecificFields.push(personSpecificFields);
    });

    return personsWithSpecificFields;
}
```

Here is my `person class`

```
import _ from 'lodash';

export default class Person{

    // not working..
    __noSuchMethod__(funcName, args){
        alert(funcName);
    }

    constructor( data ){
        this.init(data);
    }

    init(data) {
        _.each(data, (value, key) => {
           this[key] = value;
        });
    }
}
```

I have gone through [Monitor All JavaScript Object Properties (magic getters and setters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985582/monitor-all-javascript-object-properties-magic-getters-and-setters), tried to implement this [JavaScript getter for all properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994143/javascript-getter-for-all-properties) but no luck.

I know i can do this by just writing another method which will transform my `first_name` to `getFirstName` and give it a shot. But is there any way to do this in `ECMA-6` way like in class.

thanks.

Comment: An object instance is simply any object. Functions are objects. As such, functions can also have properties, which can also be other methods. If you want a "callable object", make it a function.

Comment: Good: You searched SO for other solutions. Bad: You found one and stopped reading after the first answer. When you do ES6 anyway, try the `Proxy` solution.

Comment: @Boldewyn let me try it sir,

Comment: [mdn: __NoSuchMethod__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod) is obsolete

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to detect access to a property that your object does not have, and deal with it -- this comes close to PHP's `__call`:

```
var person = new Person();
// Wrap the object in a proxy
var person = new Proxy(person, {
    get: function(person, field) {
        if (field in person) return person[field]; // normal case
        console.log("Access to non-existent property '" + field + "'");
        // Check some particular cases:
        if (field == 'first_name') return person.getFirstName;
        // ...
        // Or other cases:
        return function () {
            // This function will be executed when property is accessed as a function
        }
    }
});
```

You could even do this in the constructor of your class:

```
class Person {
    constructor(data) {
        this.init(data);
        return new Proxy(this, {
            get: function(person, field) {
                if (field in person) return person[field]; // normal case
                console.log("Access to non-existent property '" + field + "'");
                // Check some particular cases:
                if (field == 'first_name') return person.getFirstName;
                // ...
                // Or other cases:
                return function () {
                    // This function will be executed when property is accessed as a function
                    return 15; // example
                }
            }
        });
    }
    // other methods ...
    //
}
```

The nice thing about proxies is that the returned object is still considered an instance of the original class. With the above code, the following will be true:

```
new Person() instanceof Person
```

Comment: sir, get is working fine for fields but not for methods

Comment: It works also for methods, but be careful to not call them in the proxy, but to return a function reference only. For instance, note how I did not add parentheses after `person.getFirstName` in the example code. Methods are in essence also properties, they just happen to be of the function type.

Answer (score 2):

There are no special `__methods()` in Javascript like in PHP, so all you have are those `getters`, `setters`, `toString()` and `valueOf()`.

You could give `Object.defineProperty()` a shot, because with that you can dynamically create getters like so:

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'first_name', {
   get: function () { return … }
});
```

[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

The result is similar to:

```
var obj = {
  get first_name () { return … }
}
```

If you need to call method of an object, you can also do it like that:

```
var prop = 'getFirstName',
    result = obj[prop]();
```

What also can be done in a `for` loop.

Comment: also `toJSON` for `JSON.stringify`