# Calling a default method in Js Object

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there any way to create an object that respond to any message? Suppose you have the following object:

```
function Dog();
Dog.prototype.speak(){
   alert("woof woof");
}
var myDog = new Dog();
```

Then when you do `myDog.speak()` you will get an alert with `"Woof woof"`. But what I want is when you call `myDog.jump()` (which is not defined in the class) you will get a default action like show the user an alert with **"you are trying to excecute an inexistent method"**.

Do you know how can I do it?

Comment: See this answer involving `__noSuchMethod__`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/994406/603003 (this is non-standard!)

Comment: I saw that but it is only for Firefox :(

Comment: There is no other way. If I may ask, why do you need such functionality?

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**: you can't.

**Long answer**: you could use [__noSuchMethod__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod) but it's not standard and there are some plans to remove it, because [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) can do the same, and more. Plus, it's a standard.
Therefore, you could use a Proxy to do that, but I would discourage to have all objects as proxies, because performance reasons.

Personally, I would just leave the language thrown it's own exception, that the developer can check in the error console.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standards-based way to do this. The closest thing is [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2FnoSuchMethod).

The closest you could get to this would be:

```
function execute(obj, message, args) {
    if (obj[message] && typeof(message) === function) {
        obj[message].call(obj, args);
    } else {
       obj[message] = function() {
           //missing method functionality a la Ruby here
       };
    }
}
```

Comment: ComFreek just said that...in his comment ^^^

Comment: It should be `typeof obj[message] === 'function'`, shouldn't it? (Also add the quotes in case someone defines the variable `function`.)

Comment: I don't think you can redefine `function` like you can with `undefined` but other than that you're correct; typeof always returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already mentioned [__noSuchMethod__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod) and [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) so I'll refrain from going into further detail on those.

Instead, I wanted to highlight another technique that *may* be able to do what you want. Please be aware that this is a ugly hack, I can't encourage it's usage and it may not even work in all of your targets. With those caveats in mind, I present you with [window.onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror):

```
window.onerror = function(err) {
  if (/has no method/.test(err)) {
    console.log('oh my: ' + err) // This is where you'd call your callback
    return true
  }

  return false
}


;(function() {
  this.foo() // will be caught by window.onerror
})()
```

This – at least in my very limited [testing](http://jsbin.com/EmABAwE/2/edit?js,console) – catches TypeErrors (in Chrome at least, mileage may vary) that signified that the method could not be found. Here are some of the reasons why you should *not* do this:

- `window.onerror` can only have one handler; if your handler is overwritten this won't work
- It catches TypeErrors globally, not just for a specific object; i.e. lot's of false positives
- It'll make it fun to debug for anyone coming in not knowing where to find this handler
- It tightly couples any bit of code you have that relies on this behavior (bad, bad, bad!)

I don't think I can stress enough how much you really shouldn't be thinking of hacking this in. Use [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) if you can, admit defeat if you can't.